# Pyspark - Pandas UDF using Cosine Similarity - Setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, pyspark, pandas-udf

Here is my schema:

```
root
 |-- embedding_init: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- embeddings: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

I'm looking to create a udf to calculate the cosine similarity between `embedding_init` and all of the embeddings within `embeddings`

Here is my attempt:

```
@pandas_udf(T.ArrayType(T.DoubleType()), PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def cosine_sim(embedding_init, embeddings):

    embedding_init = np.array([embedding_init])
    embeddings = np.array(embeddings)

    sims = cosine_similarity(embedding_init, embeddings)[0]
    
    return sims

df.withColumn("cosine_similarity", cosine_sim(df.embedding_init, df.embeddings))
```

When I do this, I constantly get the following error:

```
  An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-90-9bd905bd9575>", line 16, in cosine_sim
  File "/artifacts/virtualenv/starscream_default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 1246, in cosine_similarity
    X, Y = check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y)
  File "/artifacts/virtualenv/starscream_default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 153, in check_pairwise_arrays
    estimator=estimator,
  File "/artifacts/virtualenv/starscream_default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 742, in check_array
    ) from complex_warning
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

More details about the data:

- There are 9 arrays within embeddings and each of them are of size 512.

Answer (score 0):

From [Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html):

> sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity(X, Y=None,
> dense_output=True)

```
Parameters:

   X{ndarray, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples_X, n_features)

        Input data.
   Y{ndarray, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples_Y, n_features), default=None
```

Looks like shape of arrays - embedding_init and  embeddings shoule be same.

E.g

If you execute your function by using below arguments it works:

```
print(cosine_sim([1.3,1.4,1.5], [[2,4,1.5],[1.2,1.4,1.5]]))
```

But with  arguments where arrays shapes are not matching, functions throws error.

```
print(cosine_sim([1.3,1.4,1.5], [[2,1.5],[1.2,1.4,1.5]]))
```

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Make sure your dataframe columns which are being used as arguments for UDF has same shapes.

Comment: I checked that and all of the arrays are the same length.

Comment: When I convert a sample to a pandas dataframe, I'm able to get it to run without issues.